# Javascript window.opener in iframe

Tags: javascript, dom, iframe, popup

I am trying to access the opener of a popup using the window.opener reference in the popup's script file.

Consider the following script included in the popup.html:

http ://localhost/test/popup.html

> ```
> <script>
>     alert(window.opener.test_dom);
> </script>
> ```

This works when no iframe is involved, we will see the alert message from popup.html:

http ://localhost/test/base.html

> ```
>  <html>
>   ...
>   <script> 
>       var test_dom = 'test_dom';
>       var popup = window.open("http://localhost/test/popup.html",...
>   </script>
>  </html>
> ```

The problem exists when there are 3 files.. a container page with an iframe in it that launches a popup from within that iframe. This does not show the alert message when popup appears:

C:\TestContainer\container.html

> ```
>  <html>
>   ...
>   <iframe src="http://localhost/test/base.html">
>       <script> 
>           var test_dom = 'test_dom';
>           var popup = window.open("http://localhost/test/popup.html",...
>       </script>
>
>   <iframe>
>  </html>
> ```

Perhaps this is a security restriction? AFAIK base.html and popup.html are in the same domain, so I see no reason why this should be. Are there other ways to access the opener via other DOM attributes in the popup.html script? I've been stuck on this for a day now.

Other than the reference to opener, everything else seems to work as expected in all scripts.

Using IE 11.

Any assistance is appreciated!

Answer (score 8):

An `iframe` does not have a `window.opener`.  It has a `window.parent` (the window in which the iframe is embedded).  If the parent is indeed the top level window, then perhaps that window has a `window.opener` if its the actual popup window.

You haven't shown your specific HTML situation, but perhaps what you want from the iframe is this:

```
window.parent.opener
```

Comment: I revised the problem to clarify that it is not an issue accessing the parent to the iframe, but rather the popup accessing the opener. In one context it works, the other, it does not (in an iframe).

Comment: @Lammy - There are intra-frame security restrictions when using URLS to the local file system.  The restrictions depend upon the browser, but you quite often cannot access things that you might think you should be able to if they are URLs in the file system.  So, that could also be part of your problem.  And, for sure you will not be able to cross frame boundaries when one frame is `http://locahost` and the other is `C:\TestContainer\container.html` as those are clearly different origins from the browser's point of view.

Comment: But, the access is not between `C:\TestContainer\container.html` and `http ://localhost`, it is between `http ://localhost/test/popup.html` and `http ://localhost/test/base.html`. It is not restricting the popup from happening either, its just restricting who the opener was, which I find strange.

Comment: @Lammy - I see what you're saying, but I'm guessing the issue goes away if you aren't using the `C:\TestContainer\container.html` origin in the mix.

Comment: I suspect that somehow there is a bug in IE 11 security causing this problem (using the parent's domain when setting opener, rather than the true opener). I agree, I suspect it will go away if my container files is also in the same domain. I wish I knew a workaround for this..

Comment: @Lammy - while searching for discussion of this topic, I came across a number of very subtle security issues and some discussion about the HTML5 spec making requirements different for top level window openers versus embedded openers.  I did not follow the entire discussion, but could see there are complicated subtleties and risks involved that it would surprise me if they lead to what you're seeing.

Comment: @Lammy - I wonder if a work-around would be to set your own property.  So, right after you create the popup window and you have the `window` object for it in your `popup` variable, you set `popup.myOpener = window`.  Like you said, those two are the same origin so you should be able to set your own custom property on the window handle and then the popup window should be able to use the `myOpener` property to get back to your other window.

Comment: Excellent idea! I gave it a shot, and after adding a poller to detect that the popup was loaded, passed the window ref as a variable to it. But, it unfortunately showed the same behavior.. worked so long as it wasn't in an iframe. Hmm..

Comment: @Lammy - OK, I guess there's some sort of security restriction for an iframe contained in a window of a different origin.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a workaround to this problem. In my situation, the popup was very simple, so what I did was embed its html in a hidden div in the base page. Then, when the popup was needed, I simply made the window show the contents of the hidden html.

Unfortunately, the event processing for the buttons found in the popup do not automatically get set when this is done, so I had to manually set them using addEventListener once the window was shown (ie, putting 'onclick' events in the html tags will not work).

```
   var popup = window.open("", "_blank", "..", false);
   var popup_html = window.document.getElementById('hidden_popup_contents').innerHTML;
   popup.document.writeln(popup_html);
   popup.document.getElementById('popup_button').addEventListener('click', SomeFunction);
```