Cross domain window.postMessage from child to parent in an iframe?
I have a parent window embedded in an iframe that opens up a child window on a button click. This is for a different domain. I need to figure out how to communicate from the child window so I can redirect the parent window once the user logs into the child popup.
The parent looks like this:
<div>
    <button data-cy="submit" data-loading-disable title="Continue" type="submit" onclick="window.open('{{ url }}', 'login', 'popup=true,rel=opener', 'width=300,height=300')"
    id="submit-button"
>
</div>

<script>
    window.addEventListener("message",
        (event) => {
            console.log("got here")
            window.location.href=event.data;
        }
    )

</script>

The child window does this when it opens:
<script>
function redirectParent(url) {
  parent.postMessage(url, "*");
}

if ("{{ redirect }}") {
  redirectParent("{{ redirect }}");
}


</script>

When I run everything, nothing seems to happen. No console logs and no redirect. Any help would be appreciated.
UPDATE: Might be worth mentioning that the child window is going throw an sso flow so there are a few redirects happening within that window.

I've also tried using window.parent.postMessage() and it seems like the window.parent object refers to itself (the child window).

Can you add the code that opens the child window?

if window.parent == window then something has disabled the parent/child link, so you won't be able to do this.

The code is there. It is the button that opens the window. I control the web apps for the child and the parent windows. Is there something I can do to make this possible? @Barmar

Sorry, I didn't scroll right to find it.

Use window.opener instead of window.parent

You're giving too many arguments to window.open(). It only takes 3 arguments, not 4. open(url, target, windowFeatures)

And rel=opener doesn't exist in window.open(). You can use noopener=true to disable the opener property. rel=opener is an HTML attribute that can be used in <a> tags.

@Barmar I've updated to onclick="window.open('{{ url }}', 'popup=true', 'width=300,height=300')" as the code that opens the window. window.opener is what I originally attempted but it seems it doesn't work with cross site requests? i.e. window.opener is null when i check in the child window.

It should be window.open('{{url}}', 'login', 'popup=true,width=300,height=300')

This looks like it may be related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31487415/javascript-window-opener-in-iframe

ah right, thanks. but that doesn't seem to be the issue here as the child <-> parent communication still isn't working. window.opener is still null and window === window.parent is still true. :/

I never meant to imply that it's related to the problem.

hm, i've looked at the as well and it doesn't seem to be exactly what i'm looking for. this is the closest i got to finding a solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8822907/html5-cross-browser-iframe-postmessage-child-to-parent
